# Passing parameters in partial Views - MVC3/Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

How can I pass parameters to a partial view in MVC3 (razor). I replaced a regular View page with a Partial View in my MVC project. For a regular View page, I passed parameters like

```
   public ActionResult MeanQ(int id)
    {            
        Access access= db.Access.Find(id);
        return View(access);
    }
```

Now since I changed the view to a partial view, I have the following code instead:

```
  public ActionResult MeanQ(int id)
    {            
        Access access= db.Access.Find(id);
        return PartialView("_MeanQPartial");
    }
```

but do not know how I can still pass the parameter 'id' to make it work like before. Please help. For what its worth, the View or the partial View , both are triggered by a link and displayed in a Jquery Modal Dialog box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
return PartialView("PartialViewName", access);
```

Comment: Thank you... I thought I tried that and it didnt work.. but it works now. I didnt test properly I think. Appreciate your help ..

Answer (score 5):

Simply give it as 2nd parameter. `PartialView` method has 4 overloads and this includes one with two parameters `PartialView(string viewName, object model)`

```
public ActionResult MeanQ(int id)
{            
    Access access= db.Access.Find(id);
    return PartialView("_MeanQPartial", access);
}
```

> For what its worth, the View or the partial View , both are triggered by a link and displayed in a Jquery Modal Dialog box.

`View` would return an entire page using your layout. `PartialView` only returns the HTML from your partial. For a modal dialog, the partial is enough. No need to retrieve a complete page.